# Laundry Box Overflow/Gurgling

Tags: plumbing, renovation

Hello I am renovating my laundry room. I have replumbed the laundry box to the best of my ability and knowledge. I am still having issues with overflow, when I stop the washer before overflow I hear gurgling by the vent pipe. It is plumbed with 2 inch pvc, with an offset to maneuver around the sill, vertical to horizontal transition under the subfloor is a wye with a cleanout. I used a laser level to measure and set the slope of both horizontal runs. I believe I calculated the offset properly. Not sure what’s causing this issue, thanks in advance for any help[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Where does that vent go?  Is that new?  Did it accidentally get capped off on the top by a roofer, etc?

Comment: I currently have the vent open about 3 feet from the top of the box (for testing purpose). The original plan was to use an AAV to end the vent, but with the overflow issues I wasn’t sure how to proceed. There is a vent stack about 6 linear feet away for the kitchen sink on a perpendicular exterior wall. I didn’t think tying into this vent made sense because it is cast iron and what seemed to be a logical tie in point is very difficult to access in the attic. I can provide more information on the prior plumbing set up if need be.

Comment: Does it gurgle and then drain pretty quickly or does it always run slow?  I ask about the vent because that’s typical when someone says gurgle.  So much of that pipe looks new, so probably not clogged unless a rag got pushed into the pipe somewhere before a proper trap was installed.  Does the other side of the wye you pictured in the crawl space drain ok?

Comment: How is the washer drain line attached to the standpipe? Is it a sealed connection or a open one?

Comment: JPhi1618 - the pipe gurgles then drains quickly. Everything I read online suggested an issue with venting or a clog. I snaked the new piping and the horizontal branch line (not sure if that is the proper term) that the washer and sink is attached. This is roughy 10-15 linear feet and ties into the sewer line seems to be 6 inch pipe. The other side of the wye drains properly ( kitchen sink )

Comment: Kris - The washer drain line is an open connection

Comment: Does it only gurgle when the washer is draining, or would it do the same thing if you poured a bucket of water in using a funnel? If it only has this problem when the washer is draining, there was another similar question asked here (that I can't find right now) and some of the answers suggested that there needs to be enough of a gap around the washer drain hose where it goes into the top of the drain pipe to allow it to draw air as the water drains. If you perfectly seal the washer output to the drain pipe, you will have an air lock there that will slow the draining.

Comment: Moshe - the still gurgles when I pour water through a funnel. I also tried with a water hose and got the same result.

Comment: is the gurgle louder at the vent pipe? does water rise up the vent pipe?

Comment: Jasen - the gurgle is louder at the vent pipe and it seems like water begins to creep up the vent pipe.